# MapView's Marker Showing Problem

Tags: android, android-mapview, markers, mapactivity

I have a MapActivity. It shows a Google map with some markers on it. While the MapActivity is running, i want to add some new markers on the map by using code, Also want to remove the previous markers so that the map will show just updated new markers, not the previous ones. How can i do that? Answers given with examples/sample codes will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance ..... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve the problem by clearing the overlay list & then invalidating the map before putting new markers on the map. That does the work for me nicely.